# git keep showing file modified on branch

Tags: git, version-control

I pulled git branch and then my git status is showing this

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/www/site1$ git status

    # On branch test
    # Changes not staged for commit:
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    #       modified:   my.sql.gz
    #
```

Then i tried following command but i keep getting same thing

```
git checkout master -- my.sql.gz
git checkout -- my.sql.gz
git stash
```

when i type git status then i get same message

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/www/site1$ git status

    # On branch test
    # Changes not staged for commit:
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    #       modified:   my.sql.gz
    #
```

Comment: What does `git diff my.sql.gz` tell you?

Comment: @Koraktor i tried that command and it executed without any output